# Bundler 2.0.1 installed, Rails says "must use Bundler 2 or greater"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, version, bundler

I'm a Rails newb who's trying out Rails on a DigitalOcean droplet. The installations seemed to work fine, but I'm getting a curious error message when I try to generate a scaffold:

```
DO 10:48 Rails/simple (master) → rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
        4: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        3: from /home/tony/rails/simple/bin/spring:10:in `<top (required)>'
        2: from /home/tony/rails/simple/bin/spring:10:in `new'
        1: from /home/tony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:95:in `initialize'
/home/tony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:108:in `warn_for_outdated_bundler_version': You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile. (Bundler::LockfileError)
DO 10:49 Rails/simple (master) → bundle list bundler
/home/tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1
DO 10:50 Rails/simple (master) → gem list bundler

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (2.0.1, default: 1.17.2)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.5)
```

I.e., the current Bundler gem is version 2.0.1, but Rails still thinks it's insufficient.

I can't find anything similar on the web. The only red flag I can see is that the bundler gem shows a default version of 1.17.2. How do I begin to diagnose the problem?

Comment: I'm in the same exact boat!

Comment: I ran into the same problem. I downgraded with `gem uninstall bundler`, followed by `gem install bundler -v 1.17.3` to revert back to the last pre 2 version. I saw this across 3 separate systems using different version managers (ASDF, rbenv, rvm) which led me to believe it wasn't ready for production use yet. You might look here: https://bundler.io/blog/2019/01/04/an-update-on-the-bundler-2-release.html try installing 1.17.2 maybe?

Comment: @JayDorsey: That worked. Thanks! If you post it as an answer, I'll accept and upvote it.

Comment: Done. I'm glad it worked!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I ran into the same issue & resolved it by downgrading with `gem uninstall bundler`, followed by `gem install bundler -v 1.17.3` to revert back to the last pre 2 version.

I saw this across 3 separate systems using different version managers (ASDF, rbenv, rvm) and this resolved the issue.

There is some information on getting both versions to play nicely [here](https://bundler.io/blog/2019/01/04/an-update-on-the-bundler-2-release.html). The root cause of this issue may have been a bug (which appears to have since been fixed)

Per the comment from @MatijsvanZuijlen below, and the bundler documentation, you should also be able to specify which version of bundler you want to use at runtime with `bundle _1.17.3_ install`

Comment: THANK YOU.  This, plus setting the Bundler version to 1.17.3 in the Gemfile.lock, resolved this.  (removing the .lock file and rerunning bundle didn't address that, but perhaps I was doing something wrong.)

Comment: Thanks guys!!! I had the same problem... downgrading to bundle 1.17.3, removing the lock file and rerunning the bundle install worked for me... :)

Comment: You don't have to remove bundler 2.0: You can also force running version 1.17.3 by running `bundle _1.17.3_`.

Comment: @MatijsvanZuijlen I had an opportunity to test that today and it doesn't seem to work (at least on my system). I have both 1.17.3 and 2.0.1 via `gem install`, 1.17.3 specified. Even though `gem list bundler` shows both versions, I get an error `Could not find 'bundler' (= 1.17.3) - did find: [bundler-2.0.1,bundler-1.7.3] (Gem::LoadError)` which is kind of odd since it seems to indicate it _can_ find 1.17.3. Hopefully this might work for others though

Comment: @JayDorsey it looks like you don't have `1.17.3`, but you do have `1.7.3` (note the minor version 17 vs 7).

Comment: @MatijsvanZuijlen that's a good catch, let me make sure that wasn't a typo!

Comment: @MatijsvanZuijlen You are correct. It does work now, it wasn't a typo, I had the wrong version installed. I must have accidentally installed 1.7.3 at some point and after the 2.0 upgrade things just broke. I know the new version was supposed to also auto-switch for you under certain conditions, I just assumed it was broken :/

Answer (score 26):

This helped me: `gem update --system`

Comment: thanks, it works for me after updating, and the error disappears.

Comment: Worked for me: rails 6, ruby 2.6

Answer (score 5):

This is my solution:

1. (if you have an old version of Bundler), run the command:

   `bundle update --bundler`
2. Run the command:

   `gem update --system`
3. run the rake

   `rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 4):

After you try any of the solutions above, restart your terminal window.

I was stuck with my terminal showing 2 versions of bundler even when i uninstalled the old version until i killed terminal and opened a new window.

Comment: I spent a lot of time trying every other answer to this question; but this was the only thing that worked.

Answer (score 2):

I got issue after updating ruby version(2.4.6) as-

> You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.

Here is how I resolved it-
When i checked bundler version `bundler -v`

```
$ Bundler version 1.16.1
```

I updated bundlere version using-

```
$ gem install bundler -v 2.0.1
```

And got issue resolved!

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I resolve it:

delete ruby and install Ruby 2.6.7 via source code, and soft link to `/usr/bin/`

```sh
wget https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.6/ruby-2.6.7.tar.gz
tar xvf ruby-2.6.7.tar.gz
./configure 
make -j32 && sudo make install
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby
```

then, run:

```sh
bundle install
```

then, run:

```
sudo bundle exec jekyll serve
```

It works for me.